# Representing associations between a class and itself

Tags: uml, associations, diagram, class-diagram

I have a class Tutor and there are some instances of that class can be course coordinators, can I represent the relationship using recursive association?
this is how I represented the association at first, which I think is not correct

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Quick fix

In your diagram you claim that **all** `Tutors` **are** `coordinating` exactly a single `Course`.  It's the consequence of [`1` being the same as `1..1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70072447/3723423).  But this is not what your narrative says:

> **some** instances of that class **can be** course coordinators.

You should therefore replace the multiplicity on the `Course` side with `0..1`.  It  which would translate some `Tutors` can be `coordinating` a `Course` (but not all).

### Another alternative

The inconvenience is that the model does not define `Course Coordinators`.  Maybe it's just the wording and doesn't matter.  But may be there is more about `Course Coordinator` that would justify a separate class with additional properties and behaviors:

- If it's a special kind of `Tutor`, just make it a specialization thereof, and let this additional class have the `coordinating` association.
- If this is a special role that a `Tutor` but also other classes (`Professor`, `Assitant`, ...) could take, you'd better prefer [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) ([object composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) in OOP corresponds to UML associations). The association between `Tutor` and `Course Coordinator` would read "have the role of".

### Not related:

A couple of additional questions for you (just to ensure that the  multiplicities say what you meant):

- One specific `Course` could be taught by several `Tutors` ?
- No `Tutor` could teach more than one `Course` ?
- A specific `Course` could have no Tutor for teaching (because `*` means `0..*`)?
- The same `Course` could be coordinated by several `Tutors`?

Comment: 1- yes 2- no a tutor can teach more than one course 3-no, I already changed the multiplicity to 1..*, 4- yes

Comment: I also changed the multiplicity of the teaching association to 1..* on the tutor side